# Why is the size of this vector 1?

Tags: java, java-me

When I use `System.out.println` to show the size of a vector after calling the following method then it shows `1` although it should show `2` because the String parameter is "`7455573;photo41.png;photo42.png`" .

```
private void getIdClientAndPhotonames(String csvClientPhotos)
{
    Vector vListPhotosOfClient = new Vector();
    String chainePhotos = "";
    String photoName = "";
    String photoDirectory = new String(csvClientPhotos.substring(0, csvClientPhotos.indexOf(';')));

    chainePhotos = csvClientPhotos.substring(csvClientPhotos.indexOf(';')+1);
    chainePhotos = chainePhotos.substring(0, chainePhotos.lastIndexOf(';'));
    if (chainePhotos.indexOf(';') == -1)
    {
        vListPhotosOfClient.addElement(new String(chainePhotos));
    }
    else    // aaa;bbb;...
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < chainePhotos.length() ; i++)
        {
            if (chainePhotos.charAt(i) == ';')
            {
                vListPhotosOfClient.addElement(new String(photoName));
                photoName = "";
                continue;
            }
            photoName = photoName.concat(String.valueOf(chainePhotos.charAt(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

So the vector should contain the two String `photo41.png and photo42.png` , but when I print the vector content I get only `photo41.png`.

So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to step through your code?

Comment: Did you try line-by-line debugging with breakpoints, to see why `addElement` isn't called for the second time? That usually helps to figure out the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use sipmly: csvClientPhotos.split(";");

Comment: Also, do you have a specific reason to use Vector? It's more common to have `List<String> photosOfClient = new ArrayList<String>()` these days.

Comment: @andy, tagged properly before submit the question.

Comment: @ArnoutEngelen there's [no List in Java ME](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/package-summary.html). Neither there are generics. [Etc etc etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDC#Noteworthy_limitations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines are the problem:

```
chainePhotos = csvClientPhotos.substring(csvClientPhotos.indexOf(';') + 1);
chainePhotos = chainePhotos.substring(0, chainePhotos.lastIndexOf(';'));
```

After the first one the `chainePhotos` contains `"photo41.png;photo42.png"`, but the second one makes it `photo41.png` - which trigers the if an ends the method with only one element in the vector.

EDITED: what a mess.

1. I ran it with correct input (as provided by the OP) and made a comment above.
2. I then fixed it as suggested above, while accidently changing the input to `7455573;photo41.png;photo42.png;` which worked, but is probably incorrect and doesn't match the explanation above input-wise.

I wish someone would un-answer this.

Comment: @Andy, you should really try answers before accepting :-) The vector will _still_ only have a single entry in it.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it with the input as provided. But I ran it with `"7455573;photo41.png;photo42.png;"` as an input (by mistake :)) - which does work and seems logical as an input.

Answer (score 4):

You have *two* immediate problems.

The first is with your initial manipulation of the string. The two lines:

```
chainePhotos = csvClientPhotos.substring(csvClientPhotos.indexOf(';')+1);
chainePhotos = chainePhotos.substring(0, chainePhotos.lastIndexOf(';'));
```

when applied to `7455573;photo41.png;photo42.png` will end up giving you `photo41.png`.

That's because the first line removes everything up to the first `;` (`7455573;`) and the second strips off everything from the final `;` onwards (`;photo42.png`). If your intent is to just get rid of the `7455573;` bit, you don't need the second line.

Note that fixing this issue alone will not solve all your ills, you still need one more change.

Even though your input string (to the loop) is the correct `photo41.png;photo42.png`, you still only add an item to the vector each time you encounter a delimiting `;`. There is *no* such delimiter at the end of that string, meaning that the final item won't be added.

You can fix this by putting the following immediately after the `for` loop:

```
if (! photoName.equals(""))
    vListPhotosOfClient.addElement(new String(photoName));
```

which will catch the case of the final name not being terminated with the `;`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is not valid for *this* question anymore, because it has been retagged to *java-me*. Still true if it was Java (like in the beginning): use `String#split` if you need to handle csv files.

---

It's be far easier to split the string:

```
 String[] parts = csvClientPhotos.split(";");
```

This will give a string array:

```
 {"7455573","photo41.png","photo42.png"}
```

Then you'd simply copy `parts[1]` and `parts[2]` to your vector.

Comment: the problem is that I use java j2me and I do not see the split method available in my editor ( Sun Java ME SDK 3 )

Comment: the problem *then* is that you used wrong tags. You clearly asked for Java.

Comment: He clearly tagged into Java ME. `string.split` not available in Java ME.

Comment: @bharath - yes, *now*. Long time after I put my answer.

Comment: Oh ok ok i didn't noticed his edit time. Anyway but this is not an answer after his edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string manually. If the string having the `;` symbol means why you can do like this? just do like this,

```
private void getIdClientAndPhotonames(String csvClientPhotos)
{
    Vector vListPhotosOfClient = split(csvClientPhotos);
}

private vector split(String original) {
Vector nodes = new Vector();
String separator = ";";
// Parse nodes into vector
int index = original.indexOf(separator);
while(index>=0) {
nodes.addElement( original.substring(0, index) );
original = original.substring(index+separator.length());
index = original.indexOf(separator);
}
// Get the last node
nodes.addElement( original );
return nodes;
}
```